# Pack python code into an executable without losing interpreting features

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I need to make an executable that gets some variables from system (Linux in my case).
I tried nuitka for this, but when testing on a different machine, I saw that it used the variables from the machine I compiled it on.
What I need is for the program to get the required data from the machine it's running on (e.g. I get the home folder of the user). It tries to search the user of the machine where the file was compiled in, what kinda ruins the whole point.

EDIT: adding code for clarification

```py
username = pexpect.run('whoami')
userpath = '/home/{}'.format(username)
filename = __file__
filename = filename[2:]
pexpect.run('cp {} {}/{}'.format(filename, userpath, filename))
```

When it's run as .py it gets everything it needs to work correctly, e.g. correct username and file name. But when I run it through nuitka and run as .exe on a different machine it uses the names as if I ran it on machine I wrote it on. E.g. '/home/user1' instead of '/home/user2' and 'filename.py' instead of 'filename.exe'.

Comment: Read [ask] Your question isn’t clear; what variables, from where? How are you converting your python code into an executable? Please edit a __minimal__ example of code into your question and explain with specific examples what it dos wrong - if there’s an error message edit the __full__ error message into your question _as text_

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The entire point of compiling source code is so that the program *does not* use the source code. That affects every feature of the source code, such as where it is located. Are you trying to get the executable location?

Comment: Well, what I need from the resulting file is to be an executable that behaves in the same way as if i just ran `python filename.py`

Comment: Note that there is no need to use ``pexpect`` to run ``whoami``, ``pwd``, or such. Python already ships with bindings for these things, such as ``os.getuid()``/``getpass.getuser()``, ``os.getcwd()``. Avoid these things especially to reconstruct *other* values that are environment dependent – for example, use ``Path.home()`` to get the home directory *even if it's not inside ``/home``*.

Comment: It seems you are looking [for this](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/467#issuecomment-513531363).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are having troubles with absolute and relative paths. You should try the following in your code:

1. Use relative paths: e.g.: instead of /usr/you/random/heresyourprogram/data, you can use simply /data instead.
2. In python there are several functions to find the current folder and the folders in the current folder. You could write an algorithm to find the current folder.
3. Or simply if you don't find the folder/file, you could always print out an error and tell the user, where should they run your program.

I hope my answer could help!

Comment: Well, I use pexpect to run bash commands (like pwd, etc) to get the info I need, so in theory it should run the same on any machine running the same OS. And I try to make sure that I never hardcode paths or similar stuff.  I edited the post with some additional information